# How to link the foreign key field to a primary key field from another table using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, primary-key

I got 2 tables for example a USER TABLE with id as primary key(auto-increment)
and a BOOKING TABLE with userid as foreign key (integer) of id in user table.
Using phpmyadmin mysql database.

How do i write a php script where i can link this two fields together so that they are always related? 
So when the user enters name and books a tour on the web form, it does everything automatically on the backend.

I am new to php and mysql and searched so many forums and watch tutorials but still dont have a clue.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are currently looking is how to join multiple tables. The query below uses an `INNER JOIN` which displays only records which has matches on both tables.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    User a
        INNER JOIN Booking b
            ON a.ID = b.userID
// WHERE    ..conditions here..
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: thnx for the help. But does this mean that for every time a new user books a tour, they will be related like how it is done in a relationship database.

Comment: how do i write that into a php script?

Comment: what do you mean by this? -- *"..they will be related like how it is done in a relationship database."*

Comment: sorry, but with the answer you gave above can only works when there are already existing records in the database. But what i am trying to do is make this work when a new user register and books a tour from the web form, it will do it automatically in the database.

Comment: that's normal because the query uses `INNER JOIN`. change it to `LEFT JOIN` isntead.

Comment: im using php to write the scripts for the web form, but i really dont know how to put the join commands as php. Sorry that im a newbie but i spent 2 whole days with fustration on this.